# How to decode image file using php

Tags: java, php, android

I'm creating an android app as well as a website using PHP. I store encoding image from android app to db. That same image I want to show in website. I tried a lot but not showing that image in website. How to decode that same image using php and shown in website.

This method, I used to encode Image from App:

```
private String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap bitmap_image = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}
```

This line to show image in PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from ACCOUNT where (company_email='$email')") or die(mysql_error());
$value = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$image = $value['PROFILE_PICTURE'];

echo '<img class="img-circle" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" width="40" height="40"/>';
```

Please, anyone help me! 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: decode and save as jpg, but I think it is not a good idea to store image encoded data in db, it will make your site slow. a good quality image contains a large encode value, try to save it as image.

Comment: Not familiar with android development, but `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` does not suggest a jpeg image...

Comment: `base64_encode($image)`. You dont have to encode it twice. $image. Is already the base64 encoded image. So just use $image instead. Well it depends on what you put in the database. How would we know?

Comment: `This line to show image in PHP:`. You cannot show images with php. You need a browser to do that. That php script only returns part of a html source. How do you invoke a browser for it?

Comment: @jeroen I tried to JPEG format also but not working

Comment: @greenapps I used just $image also but there is no use

Comment: You have to answer all comments to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps I tried all the ways but didn't get. I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: your $image contain base64 representation. You need to decode it. Please see my answer below

Comment: `You need to decode it.`@John Riddick No not al all. You can see OP needs it encoded. If things are good practice is irrelevant at the moment i think. But... we do not know how OP stores it.

Comment: `I don't know where I'm wrong. ` Ok. But how can we know if you dont show how and what you store in the database to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps Abu is clearly asking How to decode image file using php and it is clear that if we are storing base 64 image in db we have to decode it if we need image.

Comment: `Abu is clearly asking How to decode image file using php`. ? Sorry. There is nothing in his post about this. `it is clear that if we are storing base 64 image in db we have to decode it if we need image`. No. Not al all. Look at `src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'`..

Comment: @greenapps Yes, that is true but Abu needs to show what exactly he has in db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126839/discussion-between-john-riddick-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 1):

Storing base 64 string into the database is not good practice.

First, convert your base 64 string into image and store image path in the database.

You can decode base 64 string into image with the help of following function:

```
function convert_base64_to_image($base64, $image_path) {
    $file = fopen($image_path, "wb"); 
    $image_raw_data = explode(',', $base64);
    // get decodable part of image
    fwrite($file, base64_decode($image_raw_data[1])); 
    fclose($file); 
    return $image_path;
}
```

Now store image path in database and you can use this path directly to display your image.

```
echo '<img class="img-circle" src="$image_path" width="40" height="40"/>';
```